# Cancel execute in case one of several Mono<Object> is empty

Tags: java, reactor

I'm a newcomer in reactive programming.
My code looks following and I cannot figure out how to return `Flux.empty()` in case `firstService.getEntity(id1)` and `secondService.getEntity(id2)` might return `Mono.empty()`

```
public Flux<Entity3> method(UUID id1, UUID id2, SomeEnum value) {
    var entity1Mono = firstService.getEntity(id1).log();   //  <-- Mono<Entity1>
    var entity2Mono = secondService.getEntity(id2).log();  //  <-- Mono<Entity2> 

    // following code should be executed in case entity1Mono AND entity2Mono are not empty
    var parrent = Flux.combineLatest(entity1Mono, entity2Mono, (entity1, entity2) -> /* build a new  entity */); // <-- Flux<Entity3>
    var child = Flux.from(entity2Mono)
                .flatMapIterable(Entity2::getChildren)
                .map(child -> /* build a new entities */); // <-- Flux<Entity3>

    var entity3 = Flux.merge(parrent, child).log();
    return thrirdService.insert(entity3);
}
```

Maybe above code could be more optimized?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
public Flux<Entity3> method(UUID id1, UUID id2, SomeEnum value) {
        var entity1Mono = firstService.getEntity(id1).log();   //  <-- Mono<Entity1>
    var entity2Mono = secondService.getEntity(id2).log();  //  <-- Mono<Entity2> 

    // following code should be executed in case entity1Mono AND entity2Mono are not empty
    var parrent = Flux.combineLatest(entity1Mono, entity2Mono, (entity1, entity2) -> /* build a new  entity */); // <-- Flux<Entity3>
    var child = entity1Mono.hasElement()
            .filter(isExist -> isExist)
            .flatMapMany(aBoolean -> Flux.from(entity2Mono)
                .filter(entity -> CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(entity.getChildren()))
                .flatMapIterable(Entity2::getChildren)
                .map(child -> /* build a new entities */)
            ); // <-- Flux<Entity3>

    var entity3 = Flux.merge(parrent, child).log();
    return thrirdService.insert(entity3);
}
```